# partial derivative chain rules

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that there is $f(a,b)$. Also suppose that $b = g(a, \text{and some other variables})$.

By chain rule, it seems that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}\frac{\partial a}{\partial a}$$.

Is this accurate?

Edit: If this is not true, how is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}$ related?

Edit 2: OK. if $f(b,c)$ and $b=g(a, z, y, x...)$ and $c = a$. Now chain rule:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\frac{\partial b}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial c}\frac{\partial c}{\partial a} = \text{this equals to the above}.$$ So, what's wrong with this?

Comment: no its not true,lets $f(x,y)=x^2+x.y^2$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2x+y^2$ but in your method $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2y+2x+y^2$

Comment: So how's my usage of chain rule wrong?

Comment: But I said $b$ is function of $a$ and other variables...

Comment: I don't think this is a difficult question... Can anyone answer? You just have to show where I got chain rule wrong...

Answer (score 1):

this equation is useful:
$$\frac{df}{da}=\frac{df}{db}\frac{db}{da}$$

Your original statement is not incorrect in thought but it is very confusing how you having it written.  Try using the following.

$$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{df}{da}\frac{da}{dt}+\frac{df}{db}\frac{db}{dt}$$
and set t = a.  It will make it easier.  If you just do the way to have it written:
$$\frac{df}{da}=\frac{df}{da}+\frac{df}{db}\frac{db}{da}$$
which is confusing.  However:
$$f(a,b)=a^2+ab^2$$
$$\frac{df}{dt}=(2a+b^2)\frac{da}{dt}+(2ab)\frac{db}{dt}$$ Then $$\frac{df}{da}=2a+b^2+2ab\frac{db}{da}$$ is alot clearer and 100% correct.

Try it out.

I believe Maisam Hedyelloo was confused by the way it is written and I cannot blame him as I would have looked at it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all are you talking about total derivative or partial derivative? The total derivative of a function $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ is given by

$$df(x_1,...,x_n)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}dx_1+...+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}dx_n$$

By definition the components in total derivative are named as partial derivative, such as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$ is the partial derivative with respect to $x_i$. Your statement about the chain rule is correct and can be stated as

$$\frac{\partial f\big(a,b(a)\big)}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\frac{db}{da}$$

By definition of partial derivative with respect to variable "a" other variables are not important (imagine them as fixed variables) if they don't depend on "a". To show it

$$\frac{\partial f\big(a,b(a,z),x,y\big)}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}\frac{db}{da}$$